# What is a GPG Key ID?

Tags: websites

I was looking on BTC jam and I came across something called a GPG Key ID, do you know what it is?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GPG. Please at least try a websearch before asking here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GPG = GNU Privacy Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard), which is a public/private key signing/encryption system.

Your GPG Key ID is a short [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) of your public key. Presumably*, BTC Jam will look up your fingerprint on Bitcoin OTC, ask you to sign something to verify that you own it, and know that it can securely use your reputation from Bitcoin OTC to show that you are reputable.

*Hopefully they have you sign something specific like "BTC Jam user xyz is Bitcoin OTC user asd, timestamp 2014-04-09 20:00:00", otherwise you just go find the highest-reputation public key on Bitcoin OTC and say it's yours.